# In Xcode when trying to bulid the project from terminal getting following error

Tags: ios, xcode, appium-ios

I am trying to build the project in xcode and it is showing the following error:

```
**Details:**
OS: 11.3.1
Appium: 1.8.1
Xcode: 9.4.1
```

**Error:**

> CodeSign
>   /Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app
>       cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent
>       export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>        Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Avnish Kumar (XXXXL8VX5D)" Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"
>                         (1c00952c-b81c-4320-a85e-6b8e345d99db)
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 2EF8A21F8016E161291E9D3CF4385C9BE954ECE5 --deep --entitlements
> ```
>
> /Users/synerzip/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/WebDriverAgent.build/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner.build/WebDriverAgentRunner.xctest.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/synerzip/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app
>   /Users/synerzip/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app:
>   replacing existing signature Warning: unable to build chain to
>   self-signed root for signer "iPhone Developer: Avnish Kumar
>   (H95UL8VX5D)"Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for
>   signer "iPhone Developer: Avnish Kumar (XXXUL8VX5D)"Warning: unable to
>   build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Developer: Avnish
>   Kumar (XXXUL8VX5D)"
>
> writeDictToFile:1278 ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to
>   /var/folders/jh/qph34py131n24_08fg7jfskm0000gp/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xcode/EmbeddedAppDeltas/41fd2302df517875c19a87caf572b16f/1f397adabb774ab506dfa4464ea90642b90e9b39/ManifestCache.plist
>   dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest   Referenced
>   from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/01AAE80E-A8A5-4B39-ABFC-55F04C4F6E13/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/01AAE80E-A8A5-4B39-ABFC-55F04C4F6E13/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest:
>   code signing blocked mmap() of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/01AAE80E-A8A5-4B39-ABFC-55F04C4F6E13/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest'
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/01AAE80E-A8A5-4B39-ABFC-55F04C4F6E13/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest:
>   code signing blocked mmap() of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/01AAE80E-A8A5-4B39-ABFC-55F04C4F6E13/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest'
>   2018-07-25 19:21:32.471 xcodebuild[3293:60965] Error
>   Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected
>   exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be
>   attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit,
>   operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}

Testing failed:
    Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted

Comment: i see some information about the warning you are getting (Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Developer: Avnish Kumar) - maybe resolve that first and see if you get any further :
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86161

Comment: @GaryO'Donoghue: i have tried tall solution given in the link but still i am getting same error. BTW i am using Habrid mobile app , for that any other setting is require?

Comment: It does seem to do with that alright, see part of your error message - "Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/...WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app"

Have a look at https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8576 and https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/756 to see if there's anything useful there